# hpack to replace cabal - Lib directory in the project root is not found

Tags: hpack

I want to replace a long but not very complicated `.cabal` file with  hpack. The structure of the project directory is
|
|- src (with the main.hs)
|- Lib With files modules Lib.A in file A.hs, Lib.B in file B.hs
...

in `package.yaml` I have

```
library:
  source-dirs: .
  exposed-modules: Lib
```

but get the error

```
Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.0.1.0_ghc-8.8.3: can't find source for Lib in ./.,
```

What is to be put into the source-dirs to find the `Lib` directory in the project root?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure but it might be a bug in both cabal and hapack

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have created an issue with hpack.